# Failed to find OAuth initiator parameter in session error while using JWT in DocuSign - Servicenow integration

Tags: oauth, jwt, integration, docusignapi, servicenow

I have one requirement to integrate Servicenow with DocuSign using REST. We are using OAuth authentication using the grant type "JWT". We have created the OAuth entity and OAuth entity profile for DocuSign which we are integrating with ServiceNow. And also created the JWT Provider and JWT Keys for that tool we are integrating with.

We need to obtain consent from DocuSign we are integrating with. For this we need to access one URL provided by the tool which we are integrating with ServiceNow. When we access the URL, it was asking to login. After that it was not giving the consent instead it throws an error message "**Failed to find OAuth initiator parameter in session**".

I have verified all the details like JWT configuration and OAuth entity and OAuth entity profile and the details are configured correctly in ServiceNow. Still not able to resolve this error.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please post include a screenshot of the OAuth profile as well as the REST message so we can help investigate?

Comment: is this OAuth to DocuSign or to ServiceNow?

Comment: I'm not able to add screenshots of the OAuth profile as my stackoverflow profile is not supporting.

Comment: We have tried the below URL for obtaining the consent from DocuSign https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com/callback

Comment: We have tried to get the user info using the endpoint below and we have got the error "404" "User not found" error. 
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo

Comment: We have tried other GET requests such as users, accounts, to get users and accounts information. We've got response code as 200 and we didn't get the required users and accounts information in the response message. Instead, we received HTML code (seems like DocuSign's login page) as a response message.

Comment: We're able to get the access token from DocuSign using JWT token. I think OAuth and JWT configurations are fine as we've got access token in exchange of our JWT token successfully. Obtaining consent was successful in DocuSign demo instance. Recently, We've migrated the integration key to Production environment and we're facing issues in obtaining consent. I'm still not able to get the user info. Is this because of not obtaining the consent from DocuSign or because of the user information not available in DocuSign, Am I not obtaining the consent? Please help me with your suggestions.